# Strange behavior of ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using following `ng-repeat` statement

```
ng-repeat="instrument in Instruments | filter : (!systemTypeCatgory?'': {CategoryTypeId : systemTypeCatgory})"
```

There is a dropdown in which `systemTypeCatgory` is selected and based on that selection next dropdown is populated using above `ng-repeat` statement.

Everythinng was working fine till I had `CategoryTypeId` from 1 to 9 in the database. Recently new category is added with `CategoryTypeId` = 10 and now whenever I selected category with Id = 1 in the first dropdown, along with items from category=1 it includes items from ategory=10 also in the second dropdown.

But the vice-versa is not happening, meaning when I select category = 10 it shows items from category = 10 only.

It is only failing when I select category = 1.
Not sure, somewhere if it is comparing 1-1 in the start or what. Somewhere it is considering `1=10` and so the items are coming from both the categories

I have tried printing the values of `CategoryTypeId` and `systemTypeCatgory` ,the code is picking them correctly.

Not getting why it is failing, any clue?

**Edit**

Tried converting everything to string and tried this harcoding also just to check

```
ng-repeat="aiisInstrument in AiisInstruments | filter : { CategoryTypeId : '1'}"
```

It is still selecting category=10 items!! Super strange behavior :(

Comment: guess you have strings somewhere, not numbers

Comment: @PetrAveryanov -   Tried that also, edited my question :(

Comment: add ':true' (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Thanks. Stangely it worked when I tried this with hardcoding `ng-repeat="aiisInstrument in AiisInstruments | filter : { ValueDomainCategoryTypeId : '1'}:true"` but still didn't work when I tried it like this `ng-repeat="aiisInstrument in AiisInstruments | filter : { ValueDomainCategoryTypeId : systemTypeCatgory}:true"`, when I tried the later one it did not show any element in the second dropdown, so somewhere it is not considering it equal

Comment: as i said before "guess you have strings somewhere"